# Magento 2 products page title showing wrong on product page

Tags: magento-2.2.5

Magento 2 products page title showing wrong on product page.

http://prntscr.com/lpbrrv

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your product from the `admin side -> edit -> click on Search Engine Optimization tab -> Meta Title, Meta Keywords, and Meta Description` make it same as your product name

run below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

check from frontend side that's it

Comment: I am not talking about Meta Title, Meta Keywords, and Meta Description. having issue with product page title. appearing another product name.  Please see the above screenshot.

Comment: I know @LalitMalav, you are talking about page title, magento 2 consider meta title as a page title so just change into meta title and clear cache